# ORACLE. Authenticating with LDAP always returns -16

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, active-directory, ldap

We're doing user authentication with LDAP from Oracle database. However authentication result is always -16 which in some examples i've seen is translated to Invalid credentials. I've searched Active directory with DBMS_LDAP.search_s and made sure that the DN i've entered is correct. Interesting thing is that the DBMS_LDAP.SIMPLE_BIND_S, with incorrect password fails to bind, with good one it binds. However when trying the same with DBMS_LDAP_UTL.AUTHENTICATE_USER, with incorrect password, incorrect DN, it always returns -16. Here's authentication example:

```
DECLARE
 ldap_host      VARCHAR2(256);
 ldap_port      PLS_INTEGER;
 ldap_user      VARCHAR2(256);
 ldap_passwd    VARCHAR2(256);
 ldap_base      VARCHAR2(256);

 retval              PLS_INTEGER;
 my_session          DBMS_LDAP.session;

 subscriber_handle   DBMS_LDAP_UTL.HANDLE;
 sub_type            PLS_INTEGER;
 subscriber_id       VARCHAR2(2000);

 my_pset_coll        DBMS_LDAP_UTL.PROPERTY_SET_COLLECTION;
 my_property_names   DBMS_LDAP.STRING_COLLECTION;
 my_property_values  DBMS_LDAP.STRING_COLLECTION;

 user_handle         DBMS_LDAP_UTL.HANDLE;
 user_id             VARCHAR2(2000);
 user_type           PLS_INTEGER;
 user_password       VARCHAR2(2000);

 my_mod_pset         DBMS_LDAP_UTL.MOD_PROPERTY_SET;


 my_attrs            DBMS_LDAP.STRING_COLLECTION;

 locate raw(4000);

BEGIN


 -- Please customize the following variables as needed

 ldap_host  := 'host' ;
 ldap_port     :=   389;
 ldap_user  := 'CN=UserName1,OU=SERVICE_ACCOUNTS,OU=Users,OU=LT,OU=PB,DC=pan,DC=int';
 ldap_passwd   :=   'SamePassword';

 sub_type      :=   DBMS_LDAP_UTL.TYPE_DN;
 subscriber_id :=   'OU=SERVICE_ACCOUNTS,OU=Users,OU=LT,OU=PB,DC=pan,DC=int';
 user_type     :=   DBMS_LDAP_UTL.TYPE_DN;
 user_id       :=   'CN=UserName2,OU=SERVICE_ACCOUNTS,OU=Users,OU=LT,OU=PB,DC=pan,DC=int';;
 user_password :=   'SamePassword';
 -- Choosing exceptions to be raised by DBMS_LDAP library.
 DBMS_LDAP.USE_EXCEPTION := TRUE;

 -----------------------------------------------
 -- Connect to the LDAP server 
 -- and obtain and ld session.
 -----------------------------------------------

 my_session := DBMS_LDAP.init(ldap_host,ldap_port);

 -----------------------------------------------
 -- Bind to the directory
 -- 
 -----------------------------------------------

 retval := DBMS_LDAP.simple_bind_s(my_session,
                                ldap_user, 
                                ldap_passwd);

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 -- Create Subscriber Handle
 -- 
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------

 retval := DBMS_LDAP_UTL.create_subscriber_handle(subscriber_handle,
                                            sub_type,
                                            subscriber_id);

 IF retval != DBMS_LDAP_UTL.SUCCESS  THEN
    -- Handle Errors
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('create_subscriber_handle returns : ' || to_char(retval));
 END IF;

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 -- Create User Handle
 -- 
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------

 retval := DBMS_LDAP_UTL.create_user_handle(user_handle,user_type,user_id);

 IF retval != DBMS_LDAP_UTL.SUCCESS  THEN
    -- Handle Errors
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('create_user_handle returns : ' || to_char(retval));
 END IF;

  ---------------------------------------------------------------------

 dbms_output.put_line(dbms_ldap_utl.locate_subscriber_for_user(
   ld                => my_session,
   user_handle       => user_handle,
   subscriber_handle => locate));

   dbms_output.put_line(DBMS_LDAP_UTL.SUCCESS);


 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 -- Set user handle properties
 -- (link subscriber to user )
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------

 retval := DBMS_LDAP_UTL.set_user_handle_properties(user_handle,
                                          DBMS_LDAP_UTL.SUBSCRIBER_HANDLE,
                                          subscriber_handle);

 IF retval != DBMS_LDAP_UTL.SUCCESS  THEN
    -- Handle Errors
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('set_user_handle_properties returns : ' || to_char(retval));
 END IF;

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 -- Authenticate User
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------

 retval := DBMS_LDAP_UTL.authenticate_user(my_session,
                                           user_handle,
                                           DBMS_LDAP_UTL.AUTH_SIMPLE,
                                           user_password,
                                           NULL);

 IF retval != DBMS_LDAP_UTL.SUCCESS  THEN
    -- Handle Errors
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('authenticate_user returns : ' || to_char(retval));
 END IF;

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 -- Free handles
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------

 DBMS_LDAP_UTL.free_handle(subscriber_handle);
 DBMS_LDAP_UTL.free_handle(user_handle);


  -- unbind from the directory  
 retval := DBMS_LDAP.unbind_s(my_session);

 IF retval != DBMS_LDAP_UTL.SUCCESS  THEN
    -- Handle Errors
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('unbind_s returns : ' || to_char(retval));
 END IF;


-- Handle Exceptions
 EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' Error code    : ' || TO_CHAR(SQLCODE));
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' Error Message : ' || SQLERRM);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' Exception encountered .. exiting');

  END;
/
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `create_subscriber_handle`? Do you just like to authenticate a user against LDAP?

Comment: I can't really say, i've copied it from somewhere and just slightly modified. We'll be using this to authenticate user's against LDAP, and to return different codes, if there's any, to let user know if password, needs to changed, expired, incorrect, etc..

Comment: -16 is `DBMS_LDAP_UTL.AUTH_FAILURE_EXCEPTION`. See the Function Return Codes: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/dev.1111/e10186/dbldputl_ref.htm#OIMAD2896

Comment: -16 authentication failed. It doesn't really tell a lot. :) As I've said im entering good PSW and good DN, but still get this. What causes authentication failure?

Comment: Hmm. Other people with the same issue. https://community.oracle.com/thread/845863?start=15&tstart=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just like to authenticate a user against LDAP it is rather simple:

```
DECLARE

    ret NUMBER;     
    ld DBMS_LDAP.SESSION;
    SUCCESS INTEGER;

    ldap_host VARCHAR2(100) := 'host';
    ldap_port INTEGER := 389;

    userDn VARCHAR2(100) := 'OU=SERVICE_ACCOUNTS,OU=Users,OU=LT,OU=PB,DC=pan,DC=int';
    userPassword VARCHAR2(100) := 'secret';
    
BEGIN
    DBMS_LDAP.USE_EXCEPTION := TRUE;
    ld := DBMS_LDAP.INIT(ldap_host, ldap_port);
    DBMS_LDAP.USE_EXCEPTION := FALSE;

    SUCCESS := DBMS_LDAP.SIMPLE_BIND_S(ld, userDn, userPassword);
    IF SUCCESS = DBMS_LDAP.SUCCESS AND userPassword IS NOT NULL THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Password is valid');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Wrong password');
    END IF;

    ret := DBMS_LDAP.UNBIND_S(ld);

END;
```

If you like to query attributes of given user you can have a look at this example:

```
DECLARE

    SUBTYPE T_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL IS INTEGER;
    -- see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/305144/how-to-use-the-useraccountcontrol-flags-to-manipulate-user-account-pro
    SKRIPT                                  CONSTANT T_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL := 1;
    ACCOUNTDISABLE                          CONSTANT T_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL := 2;
    HOMEDIR_REQUIRED                        CONSTANT T_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL := 8;
    LOCKOUT                                     CONSTANT T_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL := 16;
    PASSWD_NOTREQD                          CONSTANT T_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL := 32;
    PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE                  CONSTANT T_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL := 64;
    ENCRYPTED_TEXT_PWD_ALLOWED          CONSTANT T_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL := 128;
    TEMP_DUPLICATE_ACCOUNT              CONSTANT T_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL := 256;
    NORMAL_ACCOUNT                          CONSTANT T_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL := 512;
    INTERDOMAIN_TRUST_ACCOUNT           CONSTANT T_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL := 2048;
    WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT           CONSTANT T_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL := 4096;
    SERVER_TRUST_ACCOUNT                    CONSTANT T_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL := 8192;
    DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD                    CONSTANT T_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL := 65536;
    MNS_LOGON_ACCOUNT                   CONSTANT T_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL := 131072;
    SMARTCARD_REQUIRED                  CONSTANT T_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL := 262144;
    TRUSTED_FOR_DELEGATION              CONSTANT T_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL := 524288;
    NOT_DELEGATED                           CONSTANT T_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL := 1048576;
    USE_DES_KEY_ONLY                        CONSTANT T_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL := 2097152;
    DONT_REQ_PREAUTH                        CONSTANT T_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL := 4194304;
    PASSWORD_EXPIRED                        CONSTANT T_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL := 8388608;
    TRUSTED_TO_AUTH_FOR_DELEGATION  CONSTANT T_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL := 16777216;
    PARTIAL_SECRETS_ACCOUNT             CONSTANT T_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL := 67108864;
    
    LDAP_USER CONSTANT VARCHAR2(255) := 'CN=UserName1,OU=SERVICE_ACCOUNTS,OU=Users,OU=LT,OU=PB,DC=pan,DC=int';
    LDAP_PASSWORD CONSTANT VARCHAR2(30) := 'secret';
    LDAP_SERVER CONSTANT VARCHAR2(30) := 'host';
    LDAP_PORT INTEGER := 389;

    userDn VARCHAR2(100) := 'CN=UserName2,OU=SERVICE_ACCOUNTS,OU=Users,OU=LT,OU=PB,DC=pan,DC=int';


    ld DBMS_LDAP.SESSION;
    ret NUMBER; 
    ldapEntry DBMS_LDAP.MESSAGE;    
    attrs DBMS_LDAP.STRING_COLLECTION;  
    ldapMessage DBMS_LDAP.MESSAGE;
    attribName VARCHAR2(256);
    berEelement DBMS_LDAP.BER_ELEMENT;
    info DBMS_LDAP.STRING_COLLECTION;
    
    pwdLastSet TIMESTAMP;
    expireDate TIMESTAMP
    
BEGIN
    
    attrs(1) := 'displayName';
    attrs(2) := 'userAccountControl';
    attrs(3) := 'pwdLastSet';

    ld := DBMS_LDAP.INIT(LDAP_SERVER, LDAP_PORT);
    ret := DBMS_LDAP.SIMPLE_BIND_S(ld, LDAP_USER, LDAP_PASSWORD);
    DBMS_LDAP.USE_EXCEPTION := FALSE;
    
    ret := DBMS_LDAP.SEARCH_S(
        ld => ld, 
        base => 'DC=pan,DC=int',
        SCOPE => DBMS_LDAP.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
        FILTER => '&(objectCategory=user)(distinguishedName='||userDn||')', 
        attrs => attrs,
        attronly => 0,
        res => ldapMessage);
    ldapEntry := DBMS_LDAP.FIRST_ENTRY(ld, ldapMessage);
    IF ldapEntry IS NULL THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('User "'||userDn||'" does not exist');
    ELSE
        WHILE ldapEntry IS NOT NULL LOOP        
            attribName := DBMS_LDAP.FIRST_ATTRIBUTE(ld, ldapEntry, berEelement);
            WHILE attribName IS NOT NULL LOOP     
                info := DBMS_LDAP.GET_VALUES(ld, ldapEntry, attribName);
                CASE attribName
                WHEN 'displayName' THEN 
                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Display Name = ' || info(info.FIRST));
                WHEN 'userAccountControl' THEN
                    IF SIGN(BITAND(ACCOUNTDISABLE, info(info.FIRST))) = 1 THEN
                        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Account is disabled');
                    END IF;
                    
                    IF SIGN(BITAND(PASSWORD_EXPIRED, info(info.FIRST))) = 1 THEN
                        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Password is expired');
                    END IF;                 
                WHEN 'pwdLastSet' THEN
                    pwdLastSet := (TIMESTAMP '1601-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + info(info.FIRST)/1000/1000/10/60/60/24 * INTERVAL '1' DAY) AT LOCAL;
                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Password was changed at ' || TO_CHAR(pwdLastSet, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));

                    -- Password life time is not available in LDAP. Check your company policy and calculate expire date accordingly, for example:
                    expireDate := pwdLastSet + INTERVAL '6' MONTH;
                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Your password will expire at ' || TO_CHAR(expireDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));                  
                END CASE;       
                attribName := DBMS_LDAP.NEXT_ATTRIBUTE(ld, ldapEntry, berEelement);
            END LOOP;
            ldapEntry := DBMS_LDAP.NEXT_ENTRY(ld, ldapEntry);
        END LOOP;
        DBMS_LDAP.BER_FREE(berEelement, freebuf => 0);  
    END IF;
    ret := DBMS_LDAP.MSGFREE(ldapMessage);
    ret := DBMS_LDAP.UNBIND_S(ld);

end;
```

**Update**

I did a mistake when I say "Password life time is not available in LDAP". You can query it like this:

```
BEGIN

   dn := 'DC=pan,DC=int';
   attrs(1) := 'maxPwdAge';

    ld := DBMS_LDAP.INIT(LDAP_SERVER, LDAP_PORT);
    ret := DBMS_LDAP.SIMPLE_BIND_S(ld, LDAP_USER, LDAP_PASSWORD);
    DBMS_LDAP.USE_EXCEPTION := FALSE;

    ret := DBMS_LDAP.SEARCH_S(
        ld => ld, 
        base => 'DC=pan,DC=int',
        SCOPE => DBMS_LDAP.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
        FILTER => '&(objectCategory=domain)(distinguishedName='||dn||')', 
        attrs => attrs,
        attronly => 0,
        res => ldapMessage);
    -- You do not need a loop because you have only one single entry and one single attribute. Otherwise a loop would be required, see above.
    ldapEntry := DBMS_LDAP.FIRST_ENTRY(ld, ldapMessage);
    attribName := DBMS_LDAP.FIRST_ATTRIBUTE(ld, ldapEntry, berEelement);
    info := DBMS_LDAP.GET_VALUES(ld, ldapEntry, attribName);    

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Password life time = ' || -info(info.FIRST)/1000/1000/10/60/60/24 || ' days');

    DBMS_LDAP.BER_FREE(berEelement, freebuf => 0);  
    ret := DBMS_LDAP.MSGFREE(ldapMessage);
    ret := DBMS_LDAP.UNBIND_S(ld);

END;
```

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful. But still, why doesn't dbms_ldap_utl.authenticate_user work? In my opinion it would be much more easier and clean to just use that, unless it was designed for some other purpose?

Comment: It would be interesting to check DBMS_LDAP_UTL body, and see what exactly fails at the authentication. Maybe some attributes in AD is configured badly.