# How to get operational attributes from LDAP using Oracle dbms_ldap or dbms_ldap_utl?

Tags: database, oracle, ldap

I would like to know how to obtain the operational attributes of an object through Oracle (DBMS_LDAP or DBMS_LDAP_UTL).
I am using a search_s:

```
--Attributes
  l_attrs(1) := '*';
  --Busqueda del usuario
  v_result := DBMS_LDAP.search_s(ld       => l_session,
                                 base     => l_ldap_base,
                                 --scope    => DBMS_LDAP.scope_onelevel,
                                 scope    =>DBMS_LDAP.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                                 filter   => '(uid=' || l_user || ')',
                                 attrs    => l_attrs,
                                 attronly => 0,
                                 res      =>  l_search_results);
```

And looping through the attributes to see them, I get these attributes but not the operational attributes

```
ATTIBUTE_NAME: centrocoste = CECO
ATTIBUTE_NAME: uid = daxint2
ATTIBUTE_NAME: mail = pepe.ramos@vvvv.com
ATTIBUTE_NAME: givenName = DAX
ATTIBUTE_NAME: tieneperfil = cn=DAX,ou=BDSS,ou=Web,ou=Perfiles,o=dax.es
ATTIBUTE_NAME: description = ES/C/DAX/DAX/DIM
ATTIBUTE_NAME: sn = DAX
ATTIBUTE_NAME: cn = I00004501
ATTIBUTE_NAME: userClass = DISTRIBUIDOR
ATTIBUTE_NAME: objectClass = daxntperson
ATTIBUTE_NAME: objectClass = organizationalPerson
ATTIBUTE_NAME: objectClass = person
ATTIBUTE_NAME: objectClass = top
ATTIBUTE_NAME: objectClass = inetOrgPerson
ATTIBUTE_NAME: userPassword = {SSHA}SGWZkMBRzyXCKRwSdsfYVTRJPVZUEMpnFyPPWA==
```

But if through "Apache directory study" I ask for the operational attributes if it has more attributes ..

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqJTe.png

I'm interested in getting "pwdChangeTime"

How can it be done?

I already tried an option from this link
[ORACLE. Authenticating with LDAP always returns -16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034079/oracle-authenticating-with-ldap-always-returns-16/49045173#49045173)
and it does not work

Thanks :)

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034079/oracle-authenticating-with-ldap-always-returns-16/49045173#49045173 - note `pwdChangeTime` is equal to `pwdLastSet`

Comment: I had already seen this link, but it does not solve the problem, because I still cannot see the operational attributes, what it does is a DBMS_LDAP.GET_VALUES and for this I must be able to see the attributes are as hidden, I do not know how to access those operational attributes because they don't appear.
Another way is to try to get the value by ID in "java" you can use getResponseControls () but in DBMS_LDAP I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Perhaps these attributes are not provided by your LDAP server. Check with tools like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/adexplorer or https://www.ldapsoft.com/adbrowserfree.html and see if they exist.