# How to view if an account is enabled/disabled, locked/unlocked in LDAP ODSEE

Tags: oracle, active-directory, ldap, identity, sailpoint

I am trying to modify accounts in LDAP(ODSEE) from SailPoint. When I view the attributes of the account in LDAP using a browser, I don't see any attributes that suggest if an account is enabled or disabled.

How can I find out an attribute of an account that carries information as to whether an account is enabled/disabled, locked/unlocked?

Do I then update my provision policy in SailPoint to include these attributes and update the values to perform the operation in LDAP?

I am fairly new to this and I am stuck so any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: See this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034079/oracle-authenticating-with-ldap-always-returns-16/49045173#49045173

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute used traditionally to lock account in Oracle is nsaccountlock, ns stand for netscape, check if this attributs exists in your ldap Schema, and create it otherwise.

src: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19225-01/820-6551/bzaoe/index.html